# Toggle Bootstrap "collapsed" Class On Two Elements

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

basically I'm developing this page here:

http://host.zadro.co/benchmarc/services.html

I need the button and accordion to sync classes.

So, if you click on either a letter or an accordion title, the "green" class will always be correct.

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts and thinking there has to be any easy way.

Comment: create a jsfiddle or bootply or better still post code here... Help us help you

Comment: the link has all the code as a live working example. if that doesn't help, I can create a jsfiddle monday. thanks much.

Comment: I took the liberty to submit an issue for this. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15741

Comment: The toggle across multiple elements was never the issue. It's getting the class to apply properly. Any hack to get this working is fine. Please append a valid workround to your answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is buggy when you have more than 1 toggle set up.

You could do something like this:

```
$("a[data-parent='.accordion']").click(function(){
  $("a[data-parent='.accordion']").addClass("collapsed")
  var href= $(this).attr("href");
  if($(href).attr("aria-expanded") == "false"){
    $("a[href='"+href+"']").removeClass("collapsed");
  }
});
```

Comment: This is great! Almost there. It doesn't work on the initial click though and takes a few clicks to catch up. Can you help more? I've updated the site.

Comment: Yeah, that's because not all the elements have the aria attribute set on page load.

Comment: yes, I added them on page load and still not working.

Comment: I'm talking about the aria attribute on the `.panel-collapse`, the one that the script is checking, since the one on the anchor tags is equally as unreliable as the collapsed class on it.

Comment: yes, the aria attribute is added. it's so close! can you take another look?

Comment: I already did take another look, I don't think you changed anything since your last comment. If you use `$(".panel-collapse")` in the console, you will see that they do not get initialized with the aria-expanded.

Comment: Ok, so I think figured it out. You need to attach this custom js before bootstrap so that it's event listener gets executed before boostrap's. There is still the shortcoming that this solution cannot handle rapid/double clicks.